FILTER on WHERE clause for each item
Below is my original WHERE clause:
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN distinctTable DT on DT.[ID] = myTable.[ID]
WHERE myTable.[Category] = '1520'

This query will return all values for myTable.[FiscalYear].
What I'm trying to do here is for each item in the INNER JOIN distinctTable DT on DT.[ID] = myTable.[ID], in the given WHERE clause, I'd like to FURTHER "filter" to it's specific fiscal year.
As an example, say that in DT.[ID] I have values with it's respective date (note that the last column is not available in the distinctTable. It is just for you to know what is the fiscal year)



ID
Close Date
Correspond to Fiscal Year (starts in Jun and ends in May)




A101
2022-04-21
FY22


A101
2024-12-10
FY25



Yes you see that right. It is not a typo error. I have the same ID but with different close date.
And that assume myTable holds 5 fiscal years (FY20 to FY24) for each cost code, given my original WHERE clause above, I'd have 10 records just for 1 cost code.



ID
Fiscal Year
Cost Code
Amount




A101
FY20
CostCode 1
10


A101
FY21
CostCode 1
20


A101
FY22
CostCode 1
30


A101
FY23
CostCode 1
40


A101
FY24
CostCode 1
50


A101
FY20
CostCode 1
100


A101
FY21
CostCode 1
200


A101
FY22
CostCode 1
300


A101
FY23
CostCode 1
400


A101
FY24
CostCode 1
500



My question is, how can I return only the relevant fiscal year for each ID, so that I can optimize my refresh speed?



ID
Fiscal Year
Cost Code
Amount




A101
FY22
CostCode 1
30


A101
FY24
CostCode 1
500



Note that fiscal period month starts in Jun and ends in May.
i.e. Jun2024 - May2025 is Fiscal 2025

Check out DatePart(yy,date)

@Bart Mcendree Is DatePart() able to distinguish the corresponding [Close Date] on the WHERE clause?

Your example data is all over the place, nothing completely matching. Please show a complete [MRE] including precise raw sample data for both tables involved in the join so we can see exactly what information is available for this filtering. And the complete query, including the select.

I don't understand the question, it's written very confusing. Please simplify it. Provide the sample input data of the affected tables and the expected result of the query.

What criteria limits the expected results to two rows instead of four - {'FY22', 30}, {'FY24', 50}, {'FY22', 300}, and {'FY24', 500}?

Add the fiscal year to your distinctTable in a WITH clause. For this just check the date's month, so you know whether you can use the date's year right away or must add 1.
WITH
  aligned AS
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      'FY' +
      CASE WHEN MONTH(close_date) >= 6 THEN
        RIGHT(YEAR(close_date) + 1, 2)
      ELSE
        RIGHT(YEAR(close_date), 2)
      END AS fy
    FROM distincttable
  )
SELECT ...
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN aligned a ON a.id = t.id 
                    AND a.fy = t.fy
WHERE t.category = 1520
...


My apologies for misleading the inital post. I've realized my error and have corrected it.
It's the same ID but with different close date. Thus the question as to 'how' to 'futher' join or where clause to "filter" out the result

@David.L: Sorry, I don't understand. You said you got too many rows because you didn't know how to properly join the tables. You joined on ID but lacked the join on the fiscal year. So I have answered that, and with my answer the issue should be solved. Now it seems you have some additional problem, and I don't understand which.

You see that in my solution I have ellipses for the SELECT clause and after WHERE, because you have not disclosed what your query does there. I assume some aggregation, (a sum or a count to get the values per ID and fiscal year probably),  but I don't know. Maybe it would be best to make that a separate request, where you show better sample data, especially including table data that leads to the result, and your whole amended query including my fiscal year join.

It won't be a problem for another 75 years, but the + 1 should really be applied before the % 100 and zero padding would be needed for FY00 - FY09. Of course, at that point, we have the Y2K bug all over again. The expression RIGHT(YEAR(close_date) + 1, 2) is an alternative, that leverages an implicit int to text conversion.Fiddle.

@T N: Thank you for pointing out the problem and showing a solution. I've updated my answer accordingly.

You can use Datepart to isolate the 4 digit year within a date.
WHERE myTable.[Category] = '1520' 
AND DatePart(yy,[Close Date]='20' + Right([Fiscal Year],2) 


You have DatePart(yy,[Close Date])=22
Wouldn't this only work for 22? And as you can see, my date varies.
For example, 2024-12-10 is FY25, so it'll be 25 not 22
But at the very least, now I know that I can try and put the AND statement in the INNER JOIN or WHERE clause.
I'll give it a try...thank you!

If you need to parse out the 22 from FY22 use Right([Fiscal Year],2)

My apologies for misleading the inital post. I've realized my error and have corrected it.
It's the same ID but with different close date. Thus the question as to 'how' to 'futher' join or where clause to "filter" out the result

I added a condition for Fiscal Year
If month <= 5 Fiscal Is CloseDate YEAR else CloseDate YEAR + 1
I'm using DATEPART function to extract the YEAR and CONCAT (self explanatory)
Fy = IIF( MONTH(CloseDate) <= 5
                 ,CONCAT('FY',DATEPART(yy,CloseDate))
                 ,CONCAT('FY',DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)+1))

After, I do the same, just to get most relevant Fiscal Year By CostCode and CloseDate
I'm using ROW_NUMBER function to create an incremental Index
RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY 
                             CostCode
                            ,IIF(MONTH(CloseDate) <= 5
                                ,DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)
                                ,DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)+1)
              ORDER BY CostCode
                      ,CloseDate desc)

And the result
    WITH T
    AS
    (
    SELECT   Id 
            ,CloseDate
            ,CostCode
            ,Amount
            ,Category
            ,Fy = IIF( MONTH(CloseDate) <= 5
                 ,CONCAT('FY',DATEPART(yy,CloseDate))
                 ,CONCAT('FY',DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)+1))
         
             ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY 
                             CostCode
                            ,IIF(MONTH(CloseDate) <= 5
                                ,DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)
                                ,DATEPART(yy,CloseDate)+1)
              ORDER BY CostCode
                      ,CloseDate desc)
     FROM MyTable
    --need a filter for 
    )
    SELECT   Id 
            ,Fy
            ,CostCode
            ,Amount
       FROM T 
      WHERE RowNum = 1

The complete result
db fiddle
I also add another CostCode for test
